# Is there a function for not-a-knot cubic splines?

Tags: r, spline, cubic-spline

I need to use the "not-a-knot" cubic spline for interpolation in my R scripts.

Although there are some R packages for splines, none of them seem to  consider the "not-a-knot" type, even if it is said to be a rather "popular" type of cubic spline, and it is available in Matlab.

I fear that there is another name for "not-a-knot" cubic splines. It is a cubic spline where the two extra conditions are about the third derivative continuity in the second and before-last knots (instead of fixing the first derivatives at the endpoint knots, as natural cubic splines do, or other choices).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By digging a little bit, it seems that this is implemented in `pracma::interp1`

From `?pracma::interp1`

> Interpolation to find ‘yi’, the values of the underlying function
> at the points in the vector ‘xi’.
> ...
> Method `spline' uses the spline approach by Moler et al., and is
> identical with the Matlab option of the same name, but slightly
> different from R's spline function.

This doesn't mention "not-a-knot", but I got there by using `sos::findFn("not-a-knot")`, which brought me to `gsignal::pulstran()`. That function's "spline" method is described as "Spline interpolation using not-a-knot end conditions";
the `method=` argument is passed directly to `pracma::interp1`.

Here is an example comparing:

- two base-R spline implementations
- `pracma::interp1`
- `pracma:::.ml.spline` (doesn't do any argument-checking, sorting, duplicate removal ... but does allow extrapolation. I don't know why `pracma::interp1` makes this restriction. The package is developed [on r-forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/?group_id=1034) but I don't see mailing lists etc., you could contact the maintainer or hack `interp1` yourself ...)
- Octave (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276990/cubic-spline-implementation-in-octave): see code below. There is an `RcppOctave` package, but it's archived and I couldn't easily get the package to install via `remotes::install_version("RcppOctave", version = "0.18-1")` - too much configuration drift ...)

```r
library(splines)
library(pracma)
x <- 1:6
y <- c(16, 18, 21, 17, 15, 12)
xi0 <- seq(1, 6, by = 0.1)
xi1 <- seq(1, 7, by = 0.1)
ys1 <- interp1(x, y, xi0, method = "spline")
ys2 <- predict(interpSpline(x, y), xi1)$y
ys3 <- spline(x, y, xout  = xi1)$y
ys4 <- pracma:::.ml.spline(x, y, xi1)
ys5 <- scan("octave_out.mat", comment = "#") ## see below

png("spline2.png")
par(las=1, bty = "l", cex = 1.5, lwd = 2)
plot(x,y, xlim = range(xi1), ylim = range(ys4),
     pch = 16, col = "gray")
cvec <- c(palette()[c(1,2,4,6)],
  ## make last color semi-transparent so we can see the overlay
          adjustcolor(palette()[5], alpha.f = 0.4))
matlines(xi1, cbind(ys2,ys3,ys4, ys5) , col = cvec[1:4], lwd = 2)
lines(xi0, ys1, lwd = 3, col = cvec[5])
legend("bottomleft",
       lty = c(1:4, 1),
       col = cvec,
       legend = c("interpSpline", "spline", ".ml.spine", "octave", "interp1"))
dev.off()
```

[image]

- Octave and `.ml.spline` output agree
- `interp1` agrees within the range of the data (no extrapolation)
- the two R splines give different, but reasonable, answers

---

Octave code (run in a separate shell)

```matlab
x = 1:6;
y = [16, 18, 21, 17, 15, 12];
xi1 = linspace(1, 7, 61);
pp = interp1(x, y, 'spline', 'pp');
yy = ppval(pp, xi1);
save octave_out.mat yy
```

Comment: Great search, and great explanation. Glad to grant you the bounty. Pitifully, Matlab spline also does extrapolation, but `pracma::interp1` complaints when trying to evaluate outside the x range

Comment: I wonder whether that restriction can be somehow overcome, since the function first assesses the arguments, and later it calls to a compiled function `.ml.spline` which may not have the restriction.